# How force Wordpress redirect to current custom page after login

Tags: redirect, login

## Problem: After login Wp redirects to either wp-admin or home (front-page.php) and not back to current page

#### I want the user to return to where he/she came from.

Ok, so this is what I've got:

I have a custom page ( page-about.php ) with bootstrap tabs (I only mention this in case it induces these problems).

The tabs are built using partials stored in template-parts and of course custom queries.

Some of these tabs contains content that should not be publically accessible. To hide it from non-logged-in users I have simply done the following:

```
<!-- template-parts/board.php -->

<div class="inner-wrapper">

   <?php
   global $post;

  // Calling the query
   $firstPage = new WP_Query(array(
      'post_type' => 'page',
      'pagename' => 'board',
      'page_id' => 317
   ));

  // Checking if user is logged in
   if (is_user_logged_in()) {
      while ($firstPage->have_posts()) : $firstPage->the_post();
   ?>

    <!-- A bunch of html in between here -->
  
      <?php endwhile;
      wp_reset_postdata();
     
     // If user is not logged in, the text below is shown asking user to log in.
   } else { ?>

      <p>You need to be logged in in order to view this content. Would you like to  <a href="<?php echo esc_url(wp_login_url()); ?>"><?php _e('log in') ?></a> now?</p>

   <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Concerning what to put inside the link fetching the `wp_login_url()`, I've also tried using

```
<?php

// Saving the current url in a var
// Hovering the link gives me: https://localhost:3000/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fmysite.local%2Fabout
$current_url = home_url( add_query_arg( [], $GLOBALS['wp']->request ) ); ?> 

<p>You need to be logged in in order to view this content. Would you like to <a href="<?php echo esc_url(wp_login_url(site_url(add_query_arg(array(), $wp->request)))); ?>" alt="<?php esc_attr_e('login', 'textdomain'); ?>"><?php _e('log in', 'textdomain'); ?></a> now?</p>
```

However I'm still being redirected to wp-admin.

I read that this may not be the optimal way of handling redirects because of how and when Wordpress tends to call the affected functions, so I also tried adding these to function.php (not at the same time obviously):

```
<?php
// #1. found on developer.wordpress.org -> login_redirect
function my_login_redirect($redirect_to, $request, $user)
{
    //is there a user to check?
    if (isset($user->roles) && is_array($user->roles)) {
        //check for admins
        if (in_array('administrator', $user->roles)) {
            // redirect them to the default place
            return $redirect_to;
        } else {
            return home_url();
        }
    } else {
        return $redirect_to;
    }
}

// #2. A modified version of the above found here on stackexchange or stackoverflow
add_filter('login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3);

function my_login_redirect($redirect_to, $requested_redirect_to, $user)
{
    if (isset($user->roles) && is_array($user->roles)) {

        if (in_array('subscriber', $user->roles)) {

            if ($requested_redirect_to && admin_url() != $requested_redirect_to) {
                $redirect_to = $requested_redirect_to;
            } else {
                $redirect_to =  home_url();
            }
        }
    }
    return $redirect_to;
}
add_filter('login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3);
?>
```

So **my main question is:** How do I force Wordpress to redirect the user *(Subscriber role)* to the same page as before logging in using a **custom page template** and custom queries? None of the above seem to apply.

Thank you and sorry for this WOT!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're inside the loop when calling the `wp_login_url()` you can just pass the `get_the_permalink()` as the $redirect url.

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_login_url( get_the_permalink() ); ?>">
   <?php echo __( 'Login' ); ?>
</a>
```

Comment: At first I did not see the connection here but after reading up on `wp_login_url()` things cleared even for me :) Thank you man!